# How to turn off Unity 3D so I can use Unity 2D on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity

I just want to turn Unity 3D off and use Unity 2D. I crunch alot of words and numbers, and when i try multitasking, Unity 3D is taking system resources that i need.

Answer (score 0):

#### According to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143639):

> Unity 2D was removed from 12.10 onwards. We now have something called llvmpipe which has the purpose of providing Unity 3D on lower specified PCs.

I don't think there will be interest in [resurrecting 2D development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_(display_server)).

I know this is not a direct answer to the question posted, but it rather leaves you with two possible choices *(if you seriously need **Unity 2D**)*:

1. Reinstall and stick with 12.04 (currently 12.04.2).
2. Use the ["fallback" session](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?s=5f31a284d7334dadb8303aba8e857a03&attachmentid=243244&d=1369844343) in either 12.10 or 13.04.